# "Intersection" of quotient groups, modulo $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, abelian-groups, integer-lattices

Let's say that $M,N$ are two invertible $n\times n$ integer matrices, such that all their eigenvalues are greater than $1$ in magnitudes. Then we define
$$K_M:=(M^{-1}\mathbb{Z}^d)\cap[0,1)^n,\quad K_N=(N^{-1}\mathbb{Z}^d)\cap[0,1)^n.$$
Then $K_M$ is precisely the complete set of representatives of distinct cosets of the quotient group $(M^{-1}\mathbb{Z}^n)/\mathbb{Z}^n$, and similarly for $K_N$.

Now let's consider 
$$K_{M,N}:=K_M\cap K_N.$$ 
If $n=1$, then we see that $M,N$ are integers with magnitudes greater than $1$. Then it's not difficult to see that $d\in K_{M,N}$ if and only if $d$ is of the form

$$\frac{j}{gcd(M,N)},\quad j=0,\dots,gcd(M,N)-1.$$
Thus in this case 
$$K_{M,N}=K_{gcd(M,N)}=(gcd(M,N)^{-1}\mathbb{Z})\cap[0,1).$$
My question is, what happens if the dimention $n\geq 2$? can we always find an invertible integer matrix $A$ such that $K_M\cap K_N=K_A$? Here $K_A=(A^{-1}\mathbb{Z}^n)\cap[0,1)^n$.

What I thought is the following: let
$$G_M:=(M^{-1}\mathbb{Z}^n)/\mathbb{Z}^n,\quad G_N:=(N^{-1}\mathbb{Z}^n)/\mathbb{Z}^n.$$
Denote

$$\Omega_{M,N}:=\{k+\mathbb{Z}^d:k\in K_{M,N}\}.$$
Then we can view $\Omega_{M,N}$ as a normal subgroup of $G_M$, and also a normal subgroup of $G_N$. Now the question becomes: is there an invertible integer matrix $A$ such that $(A^{-1}\mathbb{Z}^n)/\mathbb{Z}^n=\Omega_{M,N}$?

At this point I cannot proceed further. Any help will be greately appreciated.

Comment: $ M^{-1} \mathbb{Z}^d \cap N^{-1} \mathbb{Z}^d$ is a lattice containing $\mathbb{Z}^d$ so of the form $A^{-1} \mathbb{Z}^d$ where $A^\top$ is the unique element of $\mathbb{Z}^{d \times d}/GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$ such that both $(BA)^{-1}M, (BA)^{-1}N $ are $\in \mathbb{Z}^{d \times d}$ iff $B \in GL_d(\mathbb{Z})$. It should be possible to interpret that in term of matrices with prime power determinant and Hermite normal forms

Comment: It is unclear why you want the eigenvalues $> 1$